# How can I match lines ending with "/1" or "/2" using a single regular expression?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm parsing lines of text and trying to remove the trailing "/1" or "/2" from the lines with a single regular expression.

Right now I have this and it works correctly:

```
  $id =~ s/\/1$//;
  $id =~ s/\/2$//;
```

How can I combine these into a single line? I tried using braces but I haven't gotten it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$id =~ s/\/[12]$//;
```

using the character class `[12]` which matches either a `1` or a `2`.

Answer (score 4):

The correct answer is already given. However, I wanted to add that when you have a slash `/` in your regex, it is a good idea to use a different delimiter. It makes it much more readable, and you don't have to escape the slash.

```
$id =~ s#/[12]$##;
```

You can use a great variety of characters as delimiters, see [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a character class - [12] would mean 1 or 2:

```
$id =~ s/\/[12]$//;
```